# Searching in multiple models' tables in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 tables

- `PC(ID, PcNAME, Brand)`
- `CellPhoness(ID, CellPhoneName, Brand)`
- `Printers(ID, PrinterName, Brand)`.

There is no relationship between the 3 tables. I would like to run a query where the user can input the search string and the program will search the 3 models for where the data exists and return the same with the Id, name, and brand in the form of a JSON response.

Comment: What you have tried till now ? Are you stuck somewhere ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair i have tried this `def searchquery(self,data):

pc = PC.objects.filter('PcName'=data).values('ID', 'PcName', Brand)
cellphone = CellPhone.objects.filter('CellPhoneName'=data).values('ID', 'CellPhoneName', Brand)
printer = Printer.objects.filter('PrinterName'=data).values('ID', 'PrinterName', Brand)

if pc:
 return pc
if cellphone:
 return cellphone
if printer:
 return printer
else:
 return Respone ("error no data found")`

but I seem to end up getting no data found for any item entered, I think am stuck with the syntax more than the logic. am a beginner at this.

Comment: @Edgar thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Get query text from query params
2. Filter based on it
3. Return serializer data

   ```
    def view(request):
        query = request.GET.get("query", None)
        pcs = PC.objects.all()
        cell_phones = CellPhone.objects.all()
        printers = Printer.objects.all()

        if query:
            pcs = pcs.filter(name__icontains=query)
            cell_phones = cell_phones.filter(name__icontains=query)
            printers = printers.filter(name__icontains=query)

        return JsonResponse({"pcs": PCSerializer(instances=pcs, many=True).data,
                            "cell_phones": CellPhoneSerializer(instances=cell_phones, many=True).data,
                            "printers": PrinterSerializer(instances=printers, many=True).data})
   ```

You'll need to create serializers for each objects, please have a look at [this documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the resource, will test it and get back to you shortly! :)